# How to write a code that would produce a plot of yz traces (setting x=constant different depths)?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

```
function model_photoreactor 

global Q H W D L

global E0 B dh n KA k 

H=0.01 % Reactor height
L=60 % Reactor Length 
W=0.4 % Reactor Width

% Wastewater flowrate (m3/day)
Q=0.05 

% operating hours
top=10

% Daily treated wastewater
Q=Q/top/3600

D=9.1e-10 % Diffusion Coefficient for phenol in wastewater
dh=4 % Thickness of the film

% Catalyst optical properties
B=1.0206 % Extinction Coefficient

%Initial Photon Flux
E0=25
 n=1 % order with respect to radiation

k=0.5226 % apparent reaction constant
KA=8.5e-4 % Equilibrium Adsorption constant 

m=0
x=linspace(0,H,25) % Solution mesh
t=linspace(0,L,25)
sol=pdepe(m,@concpde,@concic, @concbc, x,t)

u = sol(:,:,1) % extraction of the first solution component from sol

subplot(1,2,1)
surf(x,t,u)
xlabel('Height')
ylabel('Length')
zlabel('Concentration')
title('(a)')

subplot(1,2,2)
 plot(t(end,:),u(:,5))
 hold on
 plot(t(end,:),u(:,10))
 hold on
 plot(t(end,:),u(:,15))
 hold on
 plot(t(end,:),u(:,20))
 hold on
 plot(t(end,:),u(:,end))
 %title('Conversion profile at different depths')
 xlabel('Photoreactor length [m]')
 ylabel('Pollutant concentration [mol/m^3]')
 legend('z=0.0002m', 'z=0.0004m', 'z=0.0006m','z=0.0008m','z=0.01m')
 title('(b)')
end 

% The mass balance equation for phenol transport through wastwater
function [c,f,s]= concpde(x,t,u,dudx) 
global Q H W D L
global E0 B dh n KA k 
As=W*H
vx=Q/As
c=vx % vx( velocity in the x direction), 
f=D*dudx
s=0 
end

%initial condition
function u0=concic(x)
u0=1;
end

% boundary conditions
function [pl,ql,pr,qr]= concbc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
global Q H W D L
global E0 B dh n KA k 
E=E0*exp(-B*dh)
rA=-E^n*k*KA*ul/(1+KA*ul)
pl=rA 
ql=D 
pr=0
qr=D
end
```

[image: Resulting plots]

In the resulting surface plot, one of the axis starts at 60, and I want to adjust this axis to start at zero instead. Also the curves in the 2 D plot are squashed, I think because the scale on the y-axis is the same as the x-axis so I want to rescale the y-axis limits although I tried using the graph inspector to change the y-axis limits however, the curves remained squashed.

Comment: You need to show the plots that cause the problem, post text as text, and pick your tags carefully

Comment: Please format the code as code. When you edit the question, there are a series of instructions that are worth reading through once, and a toolbar. The toolbar will help you apply formatting.